# Autocorrection of wrong spelled Partner name and product name, if available in a sentence with the help of existing dataset using AI/ML

Tags: python, classification, text-classification, aiml

I am working in a module where I Need to auto correct wrong spelled Partner name and Product Name (if available) in a query statement with the help of existing dataset in any form, using AI/ML.

So basically two actions are there which we need to do.

1. Finding wrong spelled Partner / Product Name based on category classification and context.
2. Correcting them.

Though, there are many paid apis available.

First, I need info on any available python lib which I can use with no cost specific to my requirement. If nothing is available free, then best paid api, which can exactly suit to this requirement.

Can anyone help me sharing the info which will be helpful for doing above.

Regards,
Kavita

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is there a single "partner" and "product name"? Is there a predefined list? Can you give an example of some input with the expected output?

Comment: Yes @Erwan, There is a predefined List. Say In - **PartnerName** we have  ABC Computers, XYZ Laser Private Limited, Techno Analytics computer etc  and in **Productname** we have Laser Printer, Inkjet Printer, HP Hardware computer etc 
 <br/>  <br/> **Input Query** is **Show me the sale of Lasr Printr in XYZ Lasr Pvt Limted**  <br/> Here You can see there is spelling mistake for Partner and Product name both. **Expected Output is** - Show me the sale of Laser Printer in XYZ Laser Private Limited.  <br/><br/>

Comment: I don't know the recent methods, maybe there is some DL char-based method. The traditional way would be to use [string similarity measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) to catch misspelled words. I'm not aware of any ready-to-use library (maybe there are), my guess is that you'd have to design and code your own system. It's a design questions so you could try to ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, maybe you'd get good suggestions.